# Haxe: How can I make the android menu bar stay hidden

Tags: android, flashdevelop, haxe, openfl

Im developing an app using haxe / openfl, with the flashdevelop ide.  The default setup for a new project comes with the correctly configured android manifest so that the android menu bars dont show up.  However when I touch anywhere on the device they pop up.  How can I prevent this from happening.

Okay, so I found the the template GameActivity.java file that the system was using to generate the apps code and modified it to include:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    if(hasFocus) {
        hideSystemUi();
    }
}

private void hideSystemUi() {
    View decorView = this.getWindow().getDecorView();

    if (Float.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE.substring(0, 3))>=4.4){

    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
    else
    {
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
}
```

Now its all working nicely.  Will post this as answer when the 8 hours are up

Comment: Sadly, it _may_ not be possible to set this up in the Manifest file. Take a look at [setting immersive mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html). It was added to a fairly recent Android API (~4.4)

Comment: By 'Menu Bars' do you mean the bar with Home button?

Comment: yes, i want to hide all the menus, including the one with the home button

Comment: Im sure this should be possible, but if not I could also go for making sure the menu stays on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're after [Immersive Sticky Mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html) that hides manu bars and software buttons on Android 4.4+. You've got it correct with setting flags via *View.setSystemUiVisibility* method.

However, one thing to keep in mind is that in Immersive Sticky Mode the menu bars will reappear if you use hardware volume buttons. To prevent it, you'll have to use a delayed Runnable that sets Immersive Sticky Mode again. You're using OpenFL so below is a set of modifications I use in my GameActivity:

```
private void setSystemUiVisibility() {
    ::if WIN_FULLSCREEN::
    ::if (ANDROID_TARGET_SDK_VERSION >= 19)::
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE |
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN |
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
        );
    }
    ::elseif (ANDROID_TARGET_SDK_VERSION >= 16)::
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN |
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE |
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE |
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        );
    }
    ::end::
    ::end::
}

private final Runnable activateImmersiveMode = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        setSystemUiVisibility();
    }
};

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
        mHandler.postDelayed(activateImmersiveMode, 500);
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setSystemUiVisibility();
    // rest of onResume()
}

@Override protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    setSystemUiVisibility();
    // rest of onStart()
}
```